# SonarQube flagging css classes in scss file as "unknown type selector" but not sure why

Tags: sass, sonarqube

We are using sass and have a snippet that looks like this:

```
.button-row {
    float: right;
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
        float: none;
        .btn, .btn-primary { <-- this line is giving us an error
            etc...
```

SonarQube is flagging that line and states:

```
Unexpected unknown type selector "    "
```

(and, yes, that's spaces in between the quotes, but it also underlines that entire line of scss as an error)

My question: What does that mean?

I'm researching this and there does seem to be a lot of issues with SASS and SonarQube specifically around custom elements. But that's not even what's happening here. This is just some (from what I can tell) perfectly valid css classes that sonarQube just doesn't like for some reason. I'm stumped.

If it matters were running SQ 7.9, so definitely a few versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through some Sonarqube bugs and it is flagging a LOT of standard CSS, SASS, LESS code which it should not.

My guess is that Sonarqube does not process these properly. I'm personally marking code that I know is correct as a false positive.